# Can't make a directory using a variables value - Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd

I'm trying to set up a simple backup process for a folder on my C drive that will back that folder up to another location on the network. I know how to create a scheduled task but I'm struggling to understand why my command prompt code won't work - I'm a novice when it comes to the Command Prompt though!

So my question is two fold:

**Why does `echo %variableName%` not return the variable value - it only returns `%variableName%`.**

This is what I type in:

```
@echo off
set varA = 5
echo %varA%
%varA%       <- This is what its popping out
```

Do I need different preceeding and succeeding characters for this?

**I want to create a folder with the date for the name (I do realize that are quite a few questions out there on this but they didn't work), how do I do it?**

Here is what I tried:

```
set folder_name = %DATE:/=_%
set folder_name                 <- Display value for folder_name
folder_name = Wed 11_06_2013    <- Actual value
```

When I try to do this:

```
mkdir %folder_name%
dir
```

Creates a folder with this `%_date%` as the name.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Space</kbd> is significant in `SET` statements.

SET var<kbd>space</kbd>=<kbd>space</kbd>value

will set a variable named "var<kbd>space</kbd>" to "<kbd>space</kbd>value"

Remove the spaces and it should be plain sailing...

Oh - except that if the variable ***contains*** a space, then commands such as `MD` or `mkdir` (which are synonyms) require `"`rabbits ears`"` around the value, thus:

mkdir "%folder_name%"

Comment: i simply can't believe how silly a mistake i made there....i'm closing this after i accept your answer